# Class 'httpRequest' not found PHP 5.3 windows

Tags: php, httprequest

I am trying to install http request class for PHP in windows.

I have downloaded a file here:

http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

php_http-5.3-nts-svn20091125-vc6-x86.zip

However, when I try to enable the extension by adding 
extension = php_http.dll to the php.ini, it does not show up in the phpinfo()

Has anyone had any success getting the httprequest class to work in windows.

This is what I am trying to do.

```
  $url = 'http://example.com/';
    //create the httprequest object

    $httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST);
```

Comment: Are you using WAMP or something similiar?

Comment: Solved it guys - I am using IIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for those using IIS 7.

The trouble is, that not all of the dll for http request are compatible and therefore wont load. Fortunately I have found the correct one.

This is the httprequest dll, that you need to install for httprequest to work:

http://www.findthatzip-file.com/search-9898866-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-php-http-5.3-nts-svn20091125-vc9-x86.zip.htm

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the extension is not in the correct folder, or you have yet to restart your webserver.

If you are using WAMP, make sure that you're editing the `php.ini` under the apache folder and not the php folder - the latter's `php.ini` is only used in the command line.

> PHP extensions are usually called "php_*.dll" (where the star represents the name of the extension) and they are located under the "PHP\ext" ("PHP\extensions" in PHP 4) folder.

For future reference: http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.windows.php

Comment: How about restarting your webserver then?

Answer (score 0):

Check the php.ini file under apache/apachex.x.xx/bin/php as well.